# In EE 2.X what replaces the submit_new_entry_end hook?

Tags: add-on, extension, hook

I'm working on converting an old 1.X extension over to EE 2.X, but my hook was 'submit_new_entry_end'. I can't seem to find a reference to what hook should replace it. My guess is '[entry_submission_absolute_end](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/extension_hooks/cp/content_publish/index.html#entry-submission-absolute-end)', but is that right?

Comment: Hey Adam, Was a big fan of the mac cast until time demands meant I had to drop it from my list of listens.  If you found an acceptable answer to your question here, please consider accepting the answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would assume so. Instead of asking yourself what hook replaces what hook, ask yourself if this describes the hook you need:

> Additional processing after entry submission, after all processing,
>   prior to redirect.

If so, entry_submission_absolute_end should be the hook you want :-)

You'll get the _entry_id, an array of meta data and an array of actual entry data, so you can do pretty much anything with it.